# How to add multiple layers to mapbox with plotly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, mapbox, streamlit

I am creating a web app where I want to add multiple layers on mapbox. There are two panda dataframes that I need to plot on the map.

As of now, I am able to do only 1 with this code.

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="Lat", lon="Long", color="x", color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Darkmint, zoom=5, text="y")

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, mapbox_style="open-street-map", height=400, width=900, hovermode='closest')

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=10))
st.write(fig)
```

Please help me on how I can add another layer with a new dataframe. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could use pydeck and st.pydeck_chart(), something like this example:

```py
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pydeck as pdk

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(1000, 2) / [50, 50] + [37.76, -122.4], columns=["lat", "lon"]
)

st.pydeck_chart(
    pdk.Deck(
        map_style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9",
        initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
            latitude=37.76, longitude=-122.4, zoom=11, pitch=50,
        ),
        layers=[
            pdk.Layer(
                "HexagonLayer",
                data=df,
                get_position="[lon, lat]",
                radius=200,
                elevation_scale=4,
                elevation_range=[0, 1000],
                pickable=True,
                extruded=True,
            ),
            pdk.Layer(
                "ScatterplotLayer",
                data=df,
                get_position="[lon, lat]",
                get_color="[200, 30, 0, 160]",
                get_radius=200,
            ),
        ],
    )
)
```